# Laptop cannot boot up

Tags: laptop, windows-10-v1607

**Product Name**: HP Pavilion G4 Laptop

**Operating System**: Microsoft Windows 10 (64-bit)

I bought it 5 years ago.

The battery isn't working anymore (I always plug in) and laptop screen also not working.(used with extra monitors.)

But now, after I tried to merge C drive with recovery drive which only have like 700mb and restarted, it is not working anymore.

I can switch on power. But nothing shows on the external monitors or the main laptop screen (since it already dead).

Mouse still lights up and keyboard num lock can still toggle.

If I press the keys from keyboard multiple times, it plays a sound. After a bit more pressing random keys, the sound doesn't stop anymore.

Can some one guide me how to fix this issue? Or what should I replace?

Hope I'm asking at the right place. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup drive image, restore from that.

If not, boot from a USB rescue drive, e.g. [Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD)](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or a Linux distro such as [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Mount the internal HDD and recover whatever files you can to another disk or to USB flash drive. That way, even if you cannot boot from your HDD, you can salvage some things.

You can download the [Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use the tool they provide to make a bootable USB or DVD. Then reinstall Windows 10, using the option to save existing files (which might or might not work). It is also possible that UBCD can resolve your issue.

However, after trying the Linux distro, if you like it better than Windows, it's easy to install from that USB drive.

Comment: Thanks. I will look how to boot from a USB rescue drive. But I'm wondering how is it possible to do it without main screen. Any tips please?

Comment: The issue is obviously with your HDD, not your screen, since you mangled the HDD. The external media has divers needed to connect to a display.